# Aggregate functions in InfluxQL are not giving output when a "tag" value is passed instead of "field"

Tags: influxql

I am using influxQL to query data from influxdb in order to see visualisations on Grafana. There are columns in the table , those are basically fields and tags, I want to count the distinct values  of a tag column by grouping it by hourly time frame.
this is my query

```sql
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT("tag")) FROM "measurement" GROUP BY time(1h)
```

I am not getting output after running this
total unique tags  = 10

```
Time         tag
1:00:00       1
1:10:10       4
1:30:10       3
1:45:00       1
2:00:00       3
2:50:00       3
3:00:00       10
3:13:00       5
```

What I am expecting -

```
Time         tag
1st hour      3  ( because 1,4,3 are 3 unique ids in that hour frame)
2nd hour      1
3rd hour      2
```

Answer (score 1):

`COUNT DISTINCT` cannot be used directly on tag (InfluxQL is not a SQL!), therefore a subquery is needed, e.g.:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "tag") as "counttag"
FROM (
    SELECT "time","tag","Value(field)"
    FROM "measurement"
    WHERE $timeFilter
)
GROUP BY time(1h)
```

Make sure you have used UTC for timestamp in the InfluxDB and keep in mind that Grafana "move" results to your local browser timezone by default.